# when visual studio is in full screen mode, how to bring taskbar "always on top"?

Tags: visual-studio, fullscreen, taskbar

How to bring the taskbar on top of Visual Studio 2008 when in "Full Screen" mode?

I often go full screen, but the task bar will become hidden.

How can I keep the task bar from hiding?

The rationale behind this is: -
We use google talk, for our quick communication in our office.
So, when I go full screen, I am not able to see the IM notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for good notifications in your instant messenger, why not give Pidgin a try? It supports more enhanced notifications like [Guifications](http://plugins.guifications.org/trac/wiki/Guifications) or you can also use Snarl - a growl clone for windows.

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to [a blog post by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/05/414910.aspx) this is the normal behavior of the task bar. That is, moving out of the way of a fullscreen window. My guess is that you can't do much about it, except not switch VS to fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/accessibility/taskbarontop.mspx

Try that...

Answer (score 1):

You can create two different VS window layouts (one normal, one "full screen") and then create shortcuts to quickly switch between them [as described by Sara Ford](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/12/05/did-you-know-you-can-create-toolbar-buttons-to-quickly-toggle-your-favorite-vs-settings-371.aspx)